# Выход из профиля Django

Tags: python, django

Я недавно сделал регистрацию и вход на сайте. Теперь мне бы хотелось,чтобы пользователь мог по нажатию кнопки выходить из своего профиля. Можете посоветовать как это сделать?

Comment: [Так](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй LogoutView

```
#urls.py

from django.contrib.auth import views as authViews

urlpatterns = [
   path('exit/', authViews.LogoutView.as_view(), name='exit'),
]
```

Comment: Я все сделал, аккаунт выходит, но проблема в том,что пользователя выкидывает на страницу Django Administration. Можете подсказать,как сделать редирект на страницу входа?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь все очень просто!

```
#urls.py

from django.contrib.auth import views as authViews

urlpatterns = [
   path('exit/', authViews.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='Здесь ссылка перенаправления'), name='exit'),
]
```